# How do you know if the shutter button is misfunctioning?

Tags: troubleshooting, shutter

I have a Panasonic GH3. It is very difficult to partially press the shutter button to focus as it often takes a picture at the slightest pressure. I thought this was my inexperience, but a couple of other people tried it recently and commented that it was overly sensitive. I don't suppose there is a setting in software to lesson the sensitivity is there? How can you tell if the shutter button needs adjusting?

Answer (score 1):

To find out if this is normal, your best bet is to try another GH3, say in a store. Without trying it out, I cannot tell if it is normal but it *could* be. In my [review of the Panasonic GH3](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/panasonic/gh3/review), I described it this way:

> This is a standard two-stage release with moderate travel to the soft halfway-point.

Indeed, the halfway-point is soft. If you push a little too hard you can easily miss it. This is why it is important to at least read about a camera's ergonomics if you cannot try it yourself.